# Best way to get the todays notifications for each user

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, django-queryset

I am working on the sample application to learn flask in that i have some models

```
class Followup(Base):

  __tablename__ = 'followup'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  status = Column(String(), nullable=False)
  next_date = Column(DateTime, default = datetime.utcnow())
  student_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('student.id'), nullable='True')
  prospect = relationship("Student", backref="followup")


class Student(Base):

  __tablename__ = 'student'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(), nullable=False)
  email = Column(String(), nullable=False)
  address = Column(String(), nullable=False)
  status = Column(String(), nullable=False) #saving active, inactive values
```

I want to get the today followup notifications for all students (i want to get student object with today follwup record if present or else none value for followup)

```
result = db_session.query(Student, Followup.status).outerjoin(Followup).filter(Student.status == "active").all()
```

here am getting the multiple records for the same student

how can I query to get each student record with today followp

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query to get all the data in one round-trip:

```
today = datetime.today()
def get_data():
    """ @return: [(student, followup), (student, followup), ...] """
    q = (session.query(Student) # get all students
        .outerjoin(Followup, and_(Student.id == Followup.student_id, func.date(Followup.next_date)==today)) # @NOTE: check for today might need to be different depending on the database used. Current code should work for mysql
        .options(contains_eager(Student.followup)) # let SA know that "followup" is loaded (line above)
        .filter(Student.status == "active") # filter only for active students
        )
    res = [(s, s.followup) for s in q.all()]
    return res

data = get_data()

# debug
for s, f in data:
    print s.name
    for _f in f:
        print "  ", _f
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just get all the followups and filter out the non-active students? The student object is available from the followup object as `followup.prospect`.

You could do that in SQLAlchemy, or just get all the followups and filter out non-active statuses like so:

```
followups = session.query(Followup).all()
active_followups = [f for f in followups if f.proscpect.status == "active"]
```

Comment: I want to display the all user in template with one notification icon for that user(to know followup him today) if he has to followup today, no icon for other users